# QTableView edit multi items same time

Tags: qt, qtableview

I use mouse select multi items of a QTableview, then I want to edit the items value  at the same time, but the default only the last item changed. I don't know how to edit items at the same time.
Please help me, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain yourself better, your question is unclear

Comment: sorry for my poor english, I changed my question.